# Блоки в html шаблоне по ширине экрана

Tags: html, css, шаблоны

Имеется шаблон, вот картинка [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно сделать так, чтобы блоки, которые c правой и левой сторон, стали почти в плотную прижаты соотвестственно к правой и левой сторонам (то есть по всей ширине), а текст в центре стал шире.

Вот сам [шаблон](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ze7vese6y04p2pj/html.zip?dl=0) (намудрил с сам все блоки по слезали)

Comment: http://htmlbook.ru/layout/fiksirovannaya-shirina-tri-kolonki

Answer (score 1):

У вас вроде вбита ширина конкретная в px, используйте проценты. И позиционирование у вас тоже абсолютное.
Можно использовать [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) для демонстрации, так удобнее, чем на дропбоксе.
Вы уверены, что вам принципиально нужен именно этот шаблон? Не проще найти что-то подходящее, чем это дорабатывать напильником?

Comment: Хотелось бы именно этот....